# Plot Y axis data based on x axis values from a csv file : Highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

What I want to do is that I want to scatter points on my graph at particular points. based on the data I have. in total, I have 1700 points data.
out of which On some points I want to plot a scatter points so that Area could be highlighted on that point.

The X-axis data Have Values as follows:

```
[33,141,240,340,441,514,645,743,852,961,1064,1172,1279,1385,1495,1607]
```

and the Values in Y-axis are:

```
[2,4,1,7,5,2,9,4,6,9,3,6,2,9,3,6]
```

But I am not getting the X-axis values. it simply counts the data from 0 to 16.

Here is the Graph I am getting :
[image: Highchart's graph]

What I want is the data to print the line until the whole 1700 points and scatter points on the Y-axis based on the X-axis data.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
               // connectorAllowed: false
            },
            data : [33,141,240,340,441,514,645,743,852,961,1064,1172,1279,1385,1495,1607]

        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [2,4,1,7,5,2,9,4,6,9,3,6,2,9,3,6]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Any Help is Really appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter The way you've structured your data doesn't look anything like their scatter plot example code

Comment: for now let's assume that We are plotting line. the problem is that I am not getting any x-ais values. How can I get the X-axis values @TKoL

Comment: You'll have to find an example of what you want in Highcharts and follow that. It doesn't look like you've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scatter plot linked in the comments by @TKoL shows two main differences from your code:

- You need to define the `chart.type` to be `scatter`
- The data should be in the format of `[[y, x]]` for the scatter plot to be able to match y to x locations.

Defining the type is fixed by adding a property to your config:

```
Hichcarts.chart("container", { 
 chart: { type: "scatter" },
 /* ... */
})
```

To zip your x and y values, you can loop over two arrays and merge based on index.

A quick one liner (might not be best performing or readable production code version):

```
const zip = (ys, xs) => 
  xs.reduce(
    (acc, x, i) => (acc.push([x, ys[i]]), acc),
    []
  );
```

<sub>Note: You might want to ensure your `xs` and `ys` are of equal length and determine the strategy when they're not (throw an error, get rid of values that are not in a pair, etc.)</sub>

Here's a minimal example that uses your data in a scatter plot:

```js
const xValues = [33, 141, 240, 340, 441, 514, 645, 743, 852, 961, 1064, 1172, 1279, 1385, 1495, 1607];

const yValues = [2, 4, 1, 7, 5, 2, 9, 4, 6, 9, 3, 6, 2, 9, 3, 6];

const zip = (ys, xs) => xs.reduce((acc, x, i) => (acc.push([x, ys[i]]), acc), []);



Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: zip(xValues, yValues)
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1s5ctbn2/

You need your series data to look like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [
    {y:2,x:1.5},
    {y:4,x:2.2},
    {y:1,x:3},
    {y:7,x:4},
    {y:5,x:5},
    {y:2,x:6},
    {y:9,x:7},
    {y:4,x:8},
    {y:6,x:9},
    {y:9,x:10},
    {y:3,x:11},
    {y:6,x:12},
    {y:2,x:13},
    {y:9,x:14},
    {y:3,x:15},
    {y:6,x:20}
    ]
}]
```

With both x and y values